# Enabling CORS in .NET 6 not working on server

Tags: c#, .net, angular, cookies, cors

I'm having some problems with **Two Factor Authentication**. I'm working with **Identity** and **IdentityServer4**, in particular I use `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` in the first POST where the user inserts username and password, that generates a cookie, and `_signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync()` in the second POST where the user inserts the otp code.

I know there are tons of threads on Cors but my problem is quite peculiar: without the "With Credentials" option the cookie can't be set with the "Set-Cookie" header, so I added it both front-end (Angular) and back-end. Then I had this CORS error:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-api-nasti.dotitsrl.it/api/web/v1/user/loginotp1' from origin '[https://nasti-test.dotitsrl.it](https://nasti-test.dotitsrl.it/)' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.*

So I added all this in my startup ConfigureService:

```
services.AddCors(optionCors =>
{
    optionCors.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins("https://nasti-test.dotitsrl.it")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .WithExposedHeaders("*")
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

and this in Configure:

```
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Now it works correctly in my local env (Windows) but doesn't work on server env (Linux), and I just don't know how is this possible. Is there something that need to be set on server?

[image]